# Outer class object not updating from inner class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerview which has an image button. In the adapter method `onBindViewHolder(..)`. I capture whether user has selected an image button or not. In the outer class I keep a reference whether user selected something or not.

I am able to capture the user selection but the outer class field does not update. I am using Kotlin here is the example.

```
class Quiz : ConstraintLayout {
constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)

// This is updated in the apdater.
private var selectedOption : String? = null

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private fun inflate(context: Context) {
    LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.image_layout, this, true) as ConstraintLayout

        viewAnimation.startTimerAnimation(7000) {
        // This always remain null. This callback is triggered after 7000 ms i.e. when animation completes.
            if (selectedOption == null)
                // do something less
            else // do something more
        }

}

inner class ImageAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        optionButton.setOnClickListener {
        // I have put a log statement here and tested the selection is captured. I also see in on the screen.
            selectedOption = imageButtonMap[holder.optionButton].toString()

        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there are more details needed here. 
As a test, I have also made that property lateinit and Kotlin throws an exception saying, lateinit property not initialized.

Comment: try  to print value inside **onBindViewHolder** and call adapter notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @RahulKhurana That did not work. Value outside the class still not updated. Any other solution?

Comment: it is working for m. What i have done that i changed value from inner class and called notifyDataSetChanged() and then print the value using Logcat. Then value is changed. Post your full code to break out the point which is not working for your case